# Connecting to MDB2 in PHP object

Tags: php, mysql, connection, persistent, mdb2

```
$dsn="mysql://$db_username:$db_password@$db_hostname/$db_database";
global $mdb2;
$mdb2=MDB2::connect($dsn);
if (PEAR::isError($mdb2))
{
    die($mdb2->getMessage());
}
```

I do this to connect to my DB, I put this in a separate php file called Connect.php and require it on all my pages.

However, when I have to query inside a function, I will have to pass $mdb2 to the function as an argument? Is this the right way to do it.

Further, I am writing a class which will query my DB. And I have no idea what to do (I don't wanna pass it as an argument)

Do I have to re-establish the connect everytime (ie. write a function for connection)

Can't you make the connection persistent and global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can require your file `Connect.php` on all of your pages, and every function that needs to use the connection can refer to the `global` variable `$mdb2`.

For example:

```
# In file Connect.php

<?php
$dsn="mysql://$db_username:$db_password@$db_hostname/$db_database";
$mdb2=MDB2::connect($dsn);
if (PEAR::isError($mdb2))
{
    die($mdb2->getMessage());
}


#In any other file

<?php
require_once "Connect.php";
getUser($id) {
    global $mdb2;
    $mdb2->query("SELECT ....");
}
```

Other solution is using a `Singleton Class` to access the database, so that there is a function that always returns the reference to your `$mdb2` variable.

Surely, the discussion [Global or Singleton for database connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130878/global-or-singleton-for-database-connection) is something worth reading.

Comment: Awesome. I got it to work.
For future reference. Here is how i got it to work within a class.
In the __construct...put global $mdb2, given you have setup $mdb2 as a global variable