# Singleton initialization configuration

Tags: php, singleton

There is a public library, and there is a class that can have only one instance in one PHP process, so it's Singleton. The problem is that initialization of this class require some configuration arguments and I can't find good issue to pass them in class constructor.

The only issue I found is:

```
    public static function init($params) {
    if(self::$instance) {
        throw new Exception(__CLASS__ . ' already initialized');
    }
    $class = __CLASS__;
    self::$instance = new $class($params);
}

public static function getInstance() {
    if(!self::$instance) {
        throw new Exception(__CLASS__ . ' is not initialized');
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

But I don't think that it's so really good.Is there any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Singleton is not an applicable pattern for classes that **can have** only one instance. It's for classes that **may have** only one instance **and** that need a a global access point to it.

Comment: And that's one reason why singletons are difficult. If you need *one* inside your app and you need to instantiate it with parameters, then you should have *one* place in your code where you write `new Foo($params)` and then inject that instance everywhere it's needed...

Comment: Singletons have very few legitimate uses and should be avoided. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9227695/477127

Comment: @deceze But in this way I can't guarantee that there will be only one instance of this class.

Comment: Yes, so? :) What's the specific reason you want yo lock down the usage of the class so hard?

Comment: @Gordon Yes, I know :) But is there any other issue for described case? As I know using different kind of "Dependency Injection" does not guarantee unique instance of class objects.

Comment: @SeniorDev why do you have to guarantee it? Will kittens die when you dont do it?

Comment: @deceze It's just very important in described case. For example: there is one STDOUT handler, and it MUST be configured on initialization, and there MUST be only one instance.

Comment: @Gordon It's just very important in described case. For example: there is one STDOUT handler, and it MUST be configured on initialization, and there MUST be only one instance.

Comment: @SeniorDev but why? what is the reason?

Comment: @Gordon It does not matter :) There is a unique case, and I need some issue. I don't ask about "how to except unique instance dependency?", I'm asking about "how to configure it?".

Comment: @SeniorDev of course it matters. In order to come up with the right solution, you need to understand what you are trying to solve and why. Otherwise, you are just assuming to need a Singleton here. So ask the Domain Expert why (five times) there MUST be only one instance and what the consequences are when there is two instances. Most of the time, it is sufficient to simply not instantiate a second instance instead of enforcing it.

Comment: If you need different configurations for it at different points in the running script, that really strongly suggests that you need more than one of it.

Comment: Hopefully, you found what you were searching for! :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is example of bad, but working issue:

```
if(!defined('PSEOUDSINGLETON_PARAM')) {
      define('PSEOUDSINGLETON_PARAM', 'default value');
}

class PseoudoSingleton {

  protected function __construct($param1 = PSEOUDSINGLETON_PARAM) { 
        // ... 
  }

  public static function getInstance() {
    if(!self::$instance) {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $class();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what you consider 'a parameterized class'? ) Btw, what do you think will happen to your __construct method if someone decides to extend your PseoudoSingleton class?

Comment: It's just example of some issue. And I already wrote that it's **bad**.

Comment: Ok, why don't you give examples of how this class will be *used* in your case (in a perfect world, and not so)? Somehow I start to think that using Factory will be much more suitable here...

Comment: class DB { protected function __construct($host = DB_HOST) { ... but it's not very good example, and it's not about my real case.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* on library/utility level */
class nonSingletonService { public function __construct($options){} }

/* on application logic level, so, knows all context */
function getSingleton(){ 
   static $inst; 
   if (!$inst) $inst=new nonSingletonService(calculateParameters()); 
   return $inst; 
}
```

Comment: Not so good, but one more really working issue. Thank you, alpaca.

Answer (score -1):

Sample Singleton implementation:

```
class MySingleton
{
   private static $_INSTANCE = null;

   private function __construct()
   {
      // put initialization code here
   }

   public static function getInstance()
   {
       if(self::$_INSTANCE === null) self::$_INSTANCE = new MySingleton();
       return self::$_INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

Note that constructor is **private**, so it can only be called from the class itself.
References to the instance can be only obtained by **getInstance** call, which creates the object on first call, any subsequent calls will return references to an existing object.

Comment: Somehow I suppose the OP knows how to use Singleton. )

Comment: @raina77ow i wasn't 100% sure when reading the code posted in question ;)

Answer (score -1):

Why are you checking it twice?

Just do the following:

```
private static function init($params) {       
    $class = __CLASS__;
    self::$instance = new $class($params);
}

public static function getInstance($params) {
    if(!self::$instance) {
        self::init($params);
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

That way, you know that you only need to check once and you know you only call init() if the instance is not initialized.

Comment: No way :(

ClassName::getInstance($params1);
ClassName::getInstance($params2); // FAIL: $params2 is ignored, developer is confused

Comment: With all due respect, the scenario you are suggesting defies the purpose of a singleton since you imply that you want to have 2 instances. Also, if you take that scenario and use it on your code you'll get the same! So the problem here is your question, not my answer!