# how to access connection variable with in another file

Tags: php, database, global-variables, undefined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global or Singleton for database connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130878/global-or-singleton-for-database-connection)

i have a database class in database.php then on the same file i create an object;
`$database = new Database();` 
Then i include this file into another file- this file has a class called `Test` inside Class `Test` has a method `test_me`.
inside test_me method i want to access $connection variable of Database class. how can i do this?

this is what i've tried;

```
function test_me(){
  global $connection;
  //use $connection on another function..
}
```

this gives me an error `undefined variable $connection` . any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Some people use `singleton`s, others use Dependency Injection. You could also look at persistent connections.

Comment: You could try `$GLOBALS['connection']` too, but I'd seriously rethink how your code is structured. You could also use a `dbconn()` function which returns a statically-declared `$connection` variable and use that in your functions (somewhat? [`singleton` pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130878/global-or-singleton-for-database-connection)). But DI with some code encapsulation is my suggestion for best practice.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare `$connection` a global variable, your code is ok.

But it is better to avoid using global variable. You could set the connection in the Test class.

An example is:

```
class Test {

  protected $connection;

  public function setConnection($connection) {
    $this->connection = $connection;
  }

  function test_me () {
    // use $this->connection.
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Dependency injection - probably the best approach if you're code is well-organized.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yep, DI is easy for test.

Comment: Y'know, and I've never figured it out, but there have been times when `global $var` didn't properly import. So I use `$GLOBALS['var']` IF necessary. Any comments appreciated on the validity of this approach.

Comment: hi, well my code is not ok for some reason, i did the same thing on another project and it worked . but this one cannot find `$connection`. however i tried your approach too, it didn't work- still cannot fine `$connection`. Are you sure using this coding part on my file will solve this? or do i have to edit another things? `$connection` is the database connection and it should be inside Database class.

Comment: @guitarlass If you set the right connection, my code will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of achieving this, something simple should be like

```
function test_me()
{
    global $database;

    echo $database->connection; // or do whatever you want with it
}
```

Comment: That's already in the question. I think the OP wants to know why it's not working.