# just one mysql connection in the all project

Tags: php, mysql

i want to know if there is a way that always i have one opened connection into my database.
i'm using this codes in my sites :

mysql class

```
class Mysql{
public static $Server   = "localhost";
static $User = 'root';
static $Password = '';
static $DataBaseName = 'teca.v1';
static $Connection;
static $DataBase;
static $LoadConnection = 0;
static $CharSet = "utf8";

static $TRANS =false;
static $TRSS  = array();

public function __construct(){
    if(Mysql::$LoadConnection==0){
        Mysql::$Connection = mysql_connect(Mysql::$Server,Mysql::$User,Mysql::$Password);
        Mysql::$DataBase   = mysql_select_db(Mysql::$DataBaseName,Mysql::$Connection);
        $charset=Mysql::$CharSet;
        mysql_query("SET NAMES $charset");
        Mysql::$LoadConnection=1;
    }
}
}
```

model class

```
class Model extends Mysql{
protected $datamembers = array();
protected $PrimaryKey="Id";
protected $TableName ="Table";
public $UnProtectedExecute = FALSE;

public  function ReadyString($value)
{
    if($this->UnProtectedExecute == TRUE)
        return addslashes($value);
    else
        return $value;
}
public function __set($variable, $value){
    $this->datamembers[strtolower($variable)] = $value;
}

public function __get($variable){
    return $this->datamembers[strtolower($variable)];
}
```

and one of my objects :

```
class LibraryFiles extends Model{
    public $TableName   = 'library_files';
}
```

but i dont know is this right and just this code create 1 connection for all of the object in my project?

Comment: yes , my objects are all inherit from model class and model from mysql

Comment: Yes and because of that it calls its constructor method and creates mysql connection.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for a PHP Singleton Database Class. Use below links to get the idea. I guess I don't have to repeat all here.

http://www.matthewelliston.com/php-singleton-database-class/

[Global or Singleton for database connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130878/global-or-singleton-for-database-connection)

[Creating the Singleton design pattern in PHP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5)

Comment: Singletons are not a very good idea. They tend to tightly couple the code to the singleton making it harder to maintain as time passes.

Answer (score 0):

Your design doesn't make very much sense. You should create separate the classes for `MySQL` and `Model`. The `MySQL` class should be instantiated once and be used throughout the whole script. So it should make only one connection.
Then let the `Model` use the instance of the `MySQL` class to operate on the data.