# Error establishing a database connection PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am using PDO to connect to MySQL

```
include_once('connection_insert.php');
global $host, $dbname, $user, $pass;
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); ///*** for error handling

function insert_terms(){
  global $DBH;
  $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO table
  (name,state) 
  value (?,?)");
  return $STH;
  $DBH = Null;// Closing Connection
}
```

But i am facing error:

> Error establishing a database connection

My question is, is this the right way use `global $DBH;` and closing connection `$DBH = Null;// Closing Connection`

**EDIT**

connection_insert.php

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$dbname = 'db';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, using `global` variables is bad practice ( dont look on Wordpress & and others uses global variables). The more complex the structure (architecture) application - the more terrible the consequences might be of using globals. You can find a lot of information why they are evil.Instead its you can use pattern  [Registry](http://avedo.net/101/the-registry-pattern-and-php/) (for example) for accessing "global" variables in application. In short, lots of choices.

Сoncerning your code. Params of connecting (`$host`,`$dbname`,`$user`,`$pass`)  are defined?

See also  [Global or Singleton for database connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130878/global-or-singleton-for-database-connection) and  [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

**EDIT**
Example :

Index.php

```
require_once 'Database.php';

$DB = new Dababase();
$DB->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO table (name,state) value (:name,:state)");
$database->bind(':name', 'NAME');
$database->bind(':state', 'STATE');
$DB->execute();
```

Config.php

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "username");
define("DB_PASS", "password");
define("DB_NAME", "database");
```

Database.php

```
require_once 'config.php'; 

class Database{
  private $host      = DB_HOST;
  private $user      = DB_USER;
  private $pass      = DB_PASS;
  private $dbname    = DB_NAME;

  private $dbh;
  private $error;
  private $stmt;

public function __construct(){
    // Set DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    try{
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }
    // Catch any errors
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
  } 

  public function prepare($query){
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
  }  

  public function query($query){
     return $this->dbh->query($query);   
  }

  public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
    if (is_null($type)) {
     switch (true) {
        case is_int($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;
        case is_bool($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            break;
        case is_null($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;
        default:
            $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
      }
   }
   $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
   } 

   public function execute(){
     return $this->stmt->execute();
   } 

   public function execute(){
     return $this->stmt->execute();
   } 

   public function fetchRows(){
     $this->execute();
     return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }

  public function fetchRow(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }

 }
```

Comment: Edited with connection_insert.php ... can you please give a small example please

Comment: Actually Registry is just improved Singleton (which also another kind of global state). There's no huge difference between global variables and singletons - as both do introduce another form of it. Instead a `Service Locator` should be used instead

Comment: @voodoo417 Thx looks good .. just 2 questions 1st- will it put less load on mysql .. as my main problem was error from sql. and 2nd can we make any function from it, i dont want to use whole statement of insert again and again ... ** INSERT IGNORE INTO..**  ... thx for good reply ;)

Comment: @Harinder updated. i am added method `query`.Good luck!