# What would cause include_once to break my code in PHP with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

The code below was not working:

```
    public function __construct($thread_id)
    {
        require_once('../private/mysqli_connect.php');
        require_once('../php_classes/class_message.php');

        $this->thread_id=$thread_id;

        $q="SELECT *
        FROM message_thread_name
        WHERE thread_id=2";

        if($r=@mysqli_query($dbc, $q))
        {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $this->poster=$row['name'];
                $this->subject=$row['thread_subject'];
            }
        }

        $qm="SELECT message_id
        FROM message
        WHERE thread_id=$this->thread_id";

        if($rm=@mysqli_query($dbc, $rm))
        {
            while($rowm=mysqli_fetch_array($rm, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $message=new message($rowm['message_id']);
                array_push($this->messages, $message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I ran out of ideas for fixing it, so I changed `require_once('../private/mysqli_connect.php');` to `require('../private/mysqli_connect.php');`, and much to my surprise, it worked. Any ideas as to why that may be?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you define what "not working" means? It's tricky to infer it in many cases. Post specific error messages or output that is unexpected so that it's easier to pin down what the issue is.

Comment: Hi. No rows were returned from mysql, presumably because the script wasn't included.

Comment: Remove @ from every where

Comment: I am guessing **$rm** is typo, it may be **$qm**??

Comment: @sectus - yup, that's a habit from before I learned what it did, because the book I learned from used it and didn't explain why.:)

Comment: @xiidea - thanks, hopefully that's resolved the other problem I'm having!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use **require_once** PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again. You can read it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

**So whats the problem here?**
From your problem statement, I am assuming you have created another instance of this class before, or you have already included **mysqli_connect.php** somewhere else. And in your **mysqli_connect.php** you have created the connection link something like.

> $dbc= mysqli_connect( ... );

So when you using require_once as the **mysqli_connect.php** is not loading again, your **$dbc** variable remain undefined. and your query does not work. But when you use **require** instead of **require_once** the file loaded again, and new connection created again, and your code works.

**NB:** Though changing to require, solved your problem, you should not use it like this. It will create new connection to your database, each time you create new instance of your class. For your thought: you can try creating something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/219599/1289495)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what should I do to fix it?

Comment: As from your question I thought you need an explanation, what I gave. And for implementation it in a perfect way, you can follow any of well known patterns like : singletone factory pattern, registry pattern. An example singleton pattern link,  I have already included in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/219599/1289495).

Comment: Ah... so to fix it, I should learn how to program. Cool. Thanks for your help. :)