# How to work with php classes and objects to communicate with mysql database - beginner in oop

Tags: php, mysql, validation, class, oop

I started learning resources from the web on object oriented programming not quite long. I have an application am working on that needs that bit of programming ability to protect against sql injections, session hijacking and brute force attacks, thereby, in the process capturing every possible information on who uses or attempted access to the application and where such activity was held. I have almost completed the application now with old fashioned php programming which I learnt on my own too. But the added functionality whereby the administrator of the application would have a tool to check the above information where necessary requires a good touch of OOP.

Here is my class file codes;

```
class Database 
{
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;
    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET CHARACTER SET utf8"
        );

        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null)
    {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function resultset()
    {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function single()
    {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function rowCount()
    {
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }

    public function lastInsertId()
    {
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function beginTransaction()
    {
        return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
    }

    public function endTransaction()
    {
        return $this->dbh->commit();
    }

    public function cancelTransaction()
    {
        return $this->dbh->rollBack();
    }

    public function debugDumpParams()
    {
        return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
    }
}
```

Then I have a test page for the database connection, created the database and attached a username and password to it.
Now the details are well entered in the php page that includes the class below like this;

```
require_once 'database.class.php';

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "username");
define("DB_PASS", "password");
define("DB_NAME", "dbname");

$database = new Database();

$database->query("CREATE TABLE mytable (
ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
LName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Age int(11) NOT NULL,
Gender enum('male','female') NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ");

$database->query('INSERT INTO mytable (FName, LName, Age, Gender)      VALUES (:fname, :lname, :age, :gender)');

$database->bind(':fname', 'John');
$database->bind(':lname', 'Smith');
$database->bind(':age', '24');
$database->bind(':gender', 'male');

$database->execute();

echo $database->lastInsertId();
```

But it throws the following error;

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\folder1\folder2\database.class.php on line 38.

Please, I need to know how I can use classes to perform operations in my database, so far, I conveniently achieve database connection and communication using `MySQL_connect($dbserver, $dbroot, $dbpwd), MySQL_select_db($dbname,$query), MySQL_query("Statement")`. Please I need a quick solution, as am currently carrying out more study and research on object oriented programming, but my project has to be finished on time. Thanks

Comment: You are calling this `$this->dbh->prepare($query);` yet have never defined the `prepare()` method in your class.

Comment: @VIDesignz, I don't know how else to define the prepare() method, am really a novice in this one, please show me a sample of what you mean.

Comment: I have to be honest, it seems like you are not gaining much creating this class as a whole. There are features that are 'neat' so to speak but there is many redundant methods that already exist when using PDO. I would rethink your whole approach personally.

Comment: If I might add, creating a class for your database connection is smart. But from that point point on, the rest is a bit...um...useless. I will add an answer that may be beneficial to you if you are alright with rethinking your approach. Let me know.

Comment: Yeah I realize that the classes would be close to useless after creating them, but for the task I want to achieve, such as saving php sessions to my database to avoid any possibility of session hijacking and also to have reference to user session records for report purposes. Most of these functionality as I discovered during its implementation would need me to use my declared class to connect to the database. But if you have another way out that is equally smart and secure, beautiful, I will love to have it, as am ready to welcome any solution. Please add your answer. Thanks

Comment: There is definitely reasons to spin off and create specialty database methods, but rewriting ones that exist just doesn't make sense. Remember, you can create any class you like! So you may consider having a "Session" class which handles everything to do with sessions, like saving them to the db, destroying them, initiating them, adjusting them and so on.

Comment: When I look at your php it looks just like a standard database interaction....

Comment: There are a lot of redundant methods in your DB class, I'd refactor it to only implement crud operations, and use PDO to ensure you won't get sql injection attacks against you...heres a quick class I wrote a while back which does what you need: https://github.com/alexmk92/ASFramework/blob/master/app/core/models/Database.php

Comment: Thanks Alex, for helping me out too. Am still a novice to so many stuffs in programming and because of the urgency on my part, I use very few knowledge gathered to integrate a real solution, as for so many stuffs on github, am not even started yet. I couldn't even implement your suggestion though because of the lagging timeframe of my current project, I have to use a substitute mysqli prepared statement. Afterwards from next weekend, i'll be soaking in studies. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok man, this should be the base class to make your database connection. Keep this as a separate file. From here you can write your custom classes for specific interactions you may want to do.

This uses PDO Prepared statements so it's close to bulletproof for sql injections.

```
<?php

/**
 * Class DatabaseFactory
 *
 * Use it like this:
 * $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
 *
 * That's my personal favourite when creating a database connection.
 * It's a slightly modified version of Jon Raphaelson's excellent answer on StackOverflow:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130878/global-or-singleton-for-database-connection
 *
 * Full quote from the answer:
 *
 * "Then, in 6 months when your app is super famous and getting dugg and slashdotted and you decide you need more than
 * a single connection, all you have to do is implement some pooling in the getConnection() method. Or if you decide
 * that you want a wrapper that implements SQL logging, you can pass a PDO subclass. Or if you decide you want a new
 * connection on every invocation, you can do do that. It's flexible, instead of rigid."
 */

/**
 * Configuration for: Database
 * DB_TYPE The used database type. Note that other types than "mysql" might break the db construction currently.
 * DB_HOST The mysql hostname, usually localhost or 127.0.0.1
 * DB_NAME The database name
 * DB_USER The username
 * DB_PASS The password
 * DB_PORT The mysql port, 3306 by default (?), find out via phpinfo() and look for mysqli.default_port.
 * DB_CHARSET The charset, necessary for security reasons. Check Database.php class for more info.
 */
$DB_TYPE = 'mysql';
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_NAME = 'db_name';
$DB_USER = 'user_name';
$DB_PASS = 'password';
$DB_PORT = '3306';
$DB_CHARSET = 'utf8';

class DatabaseFactory
{
    private static $factory;
    private $database;

    public static function getFactory()
    {
        if (!self::$factory) {
            self::$factory = new DatabaseFactory();
        }
        return self::$factory;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        if (!$this->database) {
            $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            $this->database = new PDO(
                $DB_TYPE . ':host=' . $DB_HOST . ';dbname=' .
                $DB_NAME . ';port=' . $DB_PORT . ';charset=' . $DB_CHARSET,
                $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $options
            );
        }
        return $this->database;
    }
}

?>
```

Then you can run your queries like so from your other classes/methods, such as `Users::doesUsernameAlreadyExist($user_name);`

```
public static function doesUsernameAlreadyExist($user_name)
{

    // Establish Connection
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    // Prepare Query
    $query = $database->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name = :user_name LIMIT 1");

    // Execute
    $query->execute(array(':user_name' => $user_name));

    // If exists, return true
    if ($query->rowCount() == 1) { return true; }

    // Default, return false
    return false;

}
```

Comment: It took me a while to be able to implement the solution for my app's sql injection, am grateful for all your responses. Am still learning oop and I tried implementing the two suggestions above, and still couldn't use it until I discovered I can achieve the same thing I want using mysqli prepared statements. Thanks so much.